# How to set variable CI_REGISTRY using gitlab_runner when running locally?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I installed `gitlab_runner.exe` and `Docker Desktop` on `Windows 10` and try to execute the following from `gitlab-ci.yml`

```
.docker-build:
  image: ${CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_GROUP_IMAGE_PREFIX}/docker:19.03.12
  services:
  - name: ${CI_DEPENDENCY_PROXY_GROUP_IMAGE_PREFIX}/docker:19.03.12-dind
    alias: docker
  before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
  - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/$IMAGE_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_ID -t $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/$IMAGE_NAME:$TAG -f $DOCKER_FILE $DOCKER_PATH
  - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/$IMAGE_NAME:$TAG
  - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/$IMAGE_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_ID
```

As I am running locally,  variables CI_REGISTRY is not getting set.  I tried the following but nothing worked

```
1.  gitlab-runner-windows-amd64.exe exec shell --env "CI_REGISTRY=gitco.com:4004" .docker-build
2.  set CI_REGISTRY=gitco.com:4004 from Windows command prompt
3.  Tried setting the variable within .gitlab-ci.yml
```

No matter, whatever I try, it does not recognize the CI_REGISTRY value and errored as follows

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://$CI_REGISTRY/v2/: dial tcp: lookup $CI_REGISTRY: no such host
```

I googled but unable to find relevant link for this issue.  Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: your runner is a shell one? If so, on windows, it's probably not `bash` so your variables do not seem substituted